# Can't get rspec test from railstutorial.org chapter 3 to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm doing the rails [tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#top) from Michael Hartl, and I can't get the test in chapter 3 to pass.

The static_pages.rb file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

The home.html.erb file:

```
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
</p>
```

And this is the result of the test:

```
An error occurred in an after hook
  ArgumentError: rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given
  occurred at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.1.
0/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:16:in `initialize'

←[31mF←[0m

Failures:

  1) Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mvisit '/static_pages/home'←[0m
     ←[31mArgumentError←[0m:
       ←[31mrack-test requires a rack application, but none was given←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top
(required)>'←[0m

Finished in 0.001 seconds
←[31m1 example, 1 failure←[0m

Failed examples:

←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7←[0m ←[36m# Static pages Home p
age should have the content 'Sample App'←[0m
```

My current version of Capybara is 2.1.0 but I tried changing version to 1.1.2 and bundle update, but didn't work aswell. 
Also tried different syntax for the test.

```
page.should have_title("Sample App")
page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Sample App')
page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Sample App')
```

My system is Windows 7, and my rails version is 4.0.8 and Ruby version is 1.9.3.

Tried searching around for the "rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given" error, and it seems I somehow need to change so that rack is not the default driver.
Well this is how my config file looks like.

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'

require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Comment: ok, so reading the stacktrace, the error isn't really in testing whether the page has "Sample App" on it... the error is `rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given` -> that's the phrase you should google. My guess is that it hasn't even got to the point of trying to get the page...it's failed before that point. probably something in your config.

Comment: What command did you use to run your tests?  Did you remember to do this step: `$ rails generate rspec:install`

Comment: Yes I did run that command. Got all the rspec files.

Comment: @Moltas, when you are asked questions, it is a good idea to answer them ALL.  What command did you use to run your tests?  That is not a 'yes' or 'no' answer.

Comment: Also post your Gemfile.